# Connect to MySQL directly from an iPad app (not via PHP, etc.)

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode, ipad, odbc

Before anyone has a chance: Yes, i know it's a bad idea. Please, don't give me a lecture on how i should use a web service instead. Thanks.

So, how could this be done?

I found this bit http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/ and thought it might do the trick. I got a bunch of ARC error messages, cleaned those out and got this error at runtime:

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not
>   present on the iPhone: pthread_cond_init$UNIX2003 called from function
>   my_thread_init in image oms.

Do i need to use something like ODBC/C?

I know that the solution might be a lengthy one, that's fine. Would be great if someone could at least point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

Since people are keen to know the reason for opting not to use a web service, here it is:

If you're creating an in-house app, the added security of a web service is next to nothing. Working directly with the DB means i need to maintain less code. Plus i don't need to create hacky PHP scripts to get things done.

FINAL CONCLUSION:

I wanted to leave a message for people who're about to do the same thing: Don't :)
Essentially your options are hacky server side scripts or Oracle proprietary mysql client you built yourself (and thus a hacky solution as well). Your choice but i'd strongly advice against it.

Comment: Tell me why you're trying to do it or I'll give you a lecture on how you should use a web service instead.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `soap` instead of allowing mysql connection via TCP.

Comment: This isn't me lecturing, because I am assuming that you have a good reason after admitting that it could mean extra work for you. I'm just curious - why the refusal to write a web script with a handful of custom APIs? If you have a MySQL database, I am assuming you are already paying for the web hosting, right?

Comment: Talk about poking the hornet's nest ;) Okay: If you're creating an in-house app, the added security of a web service is next to nothing. Working directly with the DB means i need to maintain less code. Plus i don't need to create hacky PHP scripts to get things done.

Comment: The pthread_cond_init$UNIX2003 function is not available on iOS but you called and weak-linked it. Rewrite your threading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the sort of thing that you are looking for:

[mysql for iphone and osx](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/)

I found it on this iphonedevsdk  thread [access mysql remote database iphone](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3711-access-mysql-remote-database-iphone.html)

Personally I would be only doing this if you really really wanted to.

If you wanted a canned solution, I also found this: [Flipper](http://itunes.apple.com/app/flipper/id299459577?mt=8)

Or to do it yourself: [Build MySql client library for iPhone/iPad](http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=20)

Its not really that hard to find a number of solutions

Comment: Thanks for the link to Build MySql client library for iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing (I understand your lecture-pain ;) ) so I wrote this: https://github.com/ciaranj/MySqueakQl it doesn't link to the mysql client libraries so no GPL issues, but it is a very minimal ... very 'fresh' i.e. untested implementation ... just my 2c.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for the input. I will definitely check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you did. I searched and find this.

In http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com/ios-4-2-gm-small-problem-with-simulator

Jean-Michel Reghem Says: 
"It seems that Apple changes (again) something into the simulator (as in iOS 4.0)."

Also some people in that page say that this problem didn't show up in device, you can try.

The author has updated his code, and it worked.

Here is the link: http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2011/06/07/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx-version-2-0/